# creating upper triangular matrix as table

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix with 100million+ rows in (i,j,x) format.  For some rows both (i,j,x) and (j,i,x) are present.  For others, only (j,i,x) (j > i) is present.  I am looking for an efficient way in which to get it into upper triangular format  (i,j,x)  (i < j).  In the instance that I have created below, mat.in is the input that I have and mat.out is the output that I need.

```
set.seed(100)
N <- 10000
M <- 1000
mat <- cbind(sample(1:M,N,replace=TRUE),sample(1:M,N,replace=TRUE),runif(N))
mat.out <- mat[mat[,1]<mat[,2],]
idx.flip <- which(runif(nrow(mat.out))<.3)
idx.del <- idx.flip[seq(1,length(idx.flip)%/%2)]
mat.in <- rbind(mat.out[-idx.del,], cbind(mat.out[,2],mat.out[,1],mat.out[,3])[idx.flip,])
```

I tried doing this using unique/aggregate (after some transformations), and they are both very slow for my instance size.

Comment: currently there are duplicated indices in your `mat.out`, is this expected?

Comment: there should not be duplicates in the output matrix

Comment: you can use `mat <- expand.grid(1:M, 1:M)` if you want to make an example with non-duplicated indices

Comment: You could try something like `inds <- mat.in[,1] > mat.in[,2]; mat.in[inds,1:2] <- mat.in[inds,2:1]; res <- mat.in[!duplicated(mat.in[,1:2]),]`

Comment: I am reading serious terminology confusion: If it has 3 dimensions it's not an R matrix. The notion of "presence" is also not clear. Do you mean `NA`?  The `mat`-object you defined has N rows and 3 columns, so could not be indexed by `[i, j, x]`.